# Validar una consulta en php

Tags: php, html, while, sql

Necesito validar una consulta para no dejar entrar al usuario a una pagina cuando esta variable que contiene la consulta esta vacia.
En el siguiente código mostraré lo que  he logrado pero hay algo que no he detectado que hace que **cuando la consulta tiene datos  sale vacía**

Esta es la consulta que guardo en la variable seleccionar

```
  $seleccionar = $conexion->query("SELECT
cl.documento,
cl.nombres as 'nombres',
cl.apellidos as 'apellidos',
cl.correo,
cl.telefono,
cl.direccion,
m.nombre as 'municipio'
FROM
tbl_cliente as cl
inner join
tblmunicipio as m ON cl.municipio = m.codigo 
WHERE documento = '$busqueda' OR nombres LIKE '%$busqueda%'OR apellidos LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
```

Aqui intento validar si la consulta esta vacía

```
        if (empty($seleccionar)) {
              echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("No existen datos que coincidan con su busqueda");
      window.location.href="registro_cliente.php";   
      </script>';
            } else{
```

Después de validar la consulta necesito imprimir los datos que trae en una tabla pero  **no me muestra nada incluso si la consulta tiene datos que mostrar**

```
            foreach($seleccionar as $datos){
             
        ?> 
            //AQUI ES DONDE MUESTRO LOS DATOS DEL WHILE
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->documento ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->nombres  ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->apellidos ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->telefono  ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->correo ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos->direccion  ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $datos->municipio   ;  ?></td>

                <td><a href="actualizar_cliente.php?documento=<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>">ACTUALIZAR</a></td>
                <td><a href="borrar_cliente.php?documento=<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>">ELIMINAR</a></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
        <?php
          }//se cierra ciclo while
       }   //se cierra condicional else
        include "../includes/desconexion.php";
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para simplificar un poco las cosas, puedes usar [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), que te va a devolver todos los resultados en un arreglo y, para que sea asociativo, envía el parámetro `MYSQLI_ASSOC`:

```
$filas = $seleccionar->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// Verificar si hay filas o no
if (empty($filas)) {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("No existen datos que coincidan con su busqueda");
  window.location.href="registro_cliente.php";   
  </script>';
} else{
```

Ahora solo necesitas el ciclo para recorrer las filas obtenidas:

```
      // TBODY debe estar fuera del ciclo
      echo '<tbody>';
      // Ciclo para recorrer resultados
      foreach($filas as $datos) { 
    ?> 
        //AQUI ES DONDE MUESTRO LOS DATOS DEL WHILE
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $datos['documento'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['nombres'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['apellidos'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['telefono'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['correo'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['direccion'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $datos['municipio'] ?></td>

            <td><a href="actualizar_cliente.php?documento=<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>">ACTUALIZAR</a></td>
            <td><a href="borrar_cliente.php?documento=<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>">ELIMINAR</a></td>
          </tr>

    <?php
      }//se cierra ciclo foreach
      echo '</tbody>';
   }   //se cierra condicional else
    include "../includes/desconexion.php";
    ?>
```

Viendo tu pregunta original, el problema estaba en la verificación:

```
   //validar consulta
    $filas  = mysqli_fetch_row($seleccionar);
    if ($filas == 0) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("No existen datos que coincidan con su busqueda");
window.location.href="registro_cliente.php";   
</script>';
    } else {
```

**Ten en cuenta que estás usando objetos** y `mysqli_fetch_row($seleccionar);` (por procedimiento) te va a dar error, porque debería ser `$seleccionar->fetch_row()`, pero, hay otro detalle con esto: Lees el primer resultado y avanzas el apuntador al siguiente registro. Si solo hay uno, ya no va a mostrar nada y, si hay más, siempre omitirá el primero.

Si quieres dejar tu código como estaba originalmente, solo necesitas contar las filas devueltas usando [`mysqli_result::num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

```
   //validar consulta
    $filas  = $seleccionar->num_rows;
    if ($filas == 0) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("No existen datos que coincidan con su busqueda");
window.location.href="registro_cliente.php";   
</script>';
    } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar la funcion 'empty($seleccionar)' directamente en tu 'if',

y en vez de utilizar el 'While' utilizar un foreach

```
foreach($datos as $item){
$item['documento']//repetir para cada campo
}
```

Comment: Gracias Editaré la pregunta , no me funcionó pero tal vez es porque lo hice mal, porfavor corrigeme si puedes.

Comment: intenta poner '$datos->documento', y deberia funcionar

Comment: Me sale este error **Notice: Trying to get property 'documento' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_cliente\buscar_cliente.php on line 109**  Editaré la pregunta de nuevo para mostrar com lo hice.

Comment: Tus enlaces de eliminar y editar aun estan con el otro tipo de llamado, prueba con comentarlos y me dices

Comment: Sale el mismo error

Comment: Si no funciona con el foreach, prueba con este ejemplo de la documentacion de php 'mysqli_fetch_row' https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php